# code working good in chrome, firefox, mircrosoft edge but not working in safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I am creating a website for my client. Website is working great in Chrome, Firefox, Microsoft Edge and Even Internet Explorer :P. But I don't know why this site is not working in Safari. This is my code:- 
HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome to Siyaram Developers</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="background"></div>
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="logo"><img src="#" width="150px" height="50px" alt="siyaram developers"/></div>
    <div id="navlinks">
        <div id="menuContainer">
            <a href="#" onclick="showContent('home')">Home</a>
            <a href="#" onclick="showContent('about-us')">About-Us</a>
            <a href="#;" onclick="showContent('projects')">Our Projects</a>
            <a href="#" onclick="showContent('vision')">Vision</a>
            <a href="#contactForm" onclick="showContent('contactForm')">Contact-Us</a>
            <a href="#login" onclick="showContent('login')">Members</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="middle">
        <div id="home">
            Welcome to the Siyaram Developers.
        </div>
        <div id="about-us">
            <h3>About Us</h3>
<p style="float: left;">
    <img src="img/a.jpg" width="250px" height="250px" alt="Sunny Bhadana" title="Sunny Bhadana"/>
</p>
<p>
    <script>
        for(i=0; i<10; i++){
            document.write("This is Some Dummy Text. This text is just for testing this site. And it's working Great.");
        }
    </script>
</p>        </div>
        <div id="vision">
            <img src="img/vision.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt="Vision" title="Vision">
<h3>Vision</h3>
<p>Our vision is to deliver positive, engaging and memorable experiences to our patrons and partners and
    continuously strive for innovation in product design and processes with integrity and transparency.</p>        </div>
        <div id="projects">
            <img src="img/company.jpg" width="100%" height="auto" alt="Project" title="Project">
<h3>Our Projects</h3>
<p>Our Project list here;---</p>        </div>
        <div id="contactForm">
        <img src="img/contact.jpg" width="100%" alt="Contact-Us">
<h3>Contact-Us</h3>
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: status in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\siyaramdevelopers\includes\contact.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
<form name="contact-form" action="index.php" method="post" onsubmit="validate()">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name"/><br/>
    <input type="number" name="number" placeholder="Your Mobile Number"/><br/>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your E-mail Address"/><br/>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your Suggestion/Questions" cols="10" rows="5"></textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>        </div>
        <div id="login">

<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="32%"><input type="button" id="log_in" onclick="show('log_in')" value="Log-In"/></td>
        <td width="32%"><input type="button" onclick="show('sign_up')" id="sign_up" value="Sign-Up"/></td>
        <td width="32%"><input type="button" onclick="show('admin_login')" id="admin_login" value="Admin Login"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" align="center">
            <form name="loginForm" onsubmit="return false;">
                <input type="email" id="login_username" placeholder="Email Address"><br/>
                <input type="password" id="login_password" placeholder="Password"><br/>
                <input type="button" onclick="validateData()" value="Login"><br/>
                <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
                <br/>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td valign="top" align="center">
            <form name="signupForm" onsubmit="return false">
                <input type="text" id="sign_name" placeholder="Your Name"/><br/>
                <input type="email" id="sign_email" placeholder="Your Email"/><br/>
                <input type="password" id="sign_password" placeholder="Password"/><br/>
                <input type="number" id="sign_mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number"/><br/>
                <input type="button" onclick="userSignUp()" value="Sign-Up" /><br/>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td valign="top" align="center">
            <form name="admin_login" onsubmit="return false">
                <input type="email" id="admin_username" placeholder="Email Address"><br/>
                <input type="password" id="admin_password" placeholder="Password"><br/>
                <input type="button" onclick="login_admin()" value="Login"><br/>
                <br/>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>



        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Java Script Code**

```
<script>
        function validateData() {
            var username = document.getElementById("login_username").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("login_password").value;
            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajax.open("POST", "login_test.php", true);
            ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
                    if(ajax.responseText == "login_undone"){
                        alert("Login Failed");
                    }else {
                        window.location.assign("user.php?username="+ajax.responseText);
                    }
                }
            }
        ajax.send("username="+username+"&password="+password);
        }

        function login_admin() {
            var admin_username = document.getElementById("admin_username").value;
            var admin_password = document.getElementById("admin_password").value;
            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajax.open("POST", "login_test.php", true);
            ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
                    if(ajax.responseText == "login_done") {
                        window.location.assign('admin/index.php');
                    }else {
                        alert('Sorry! Wrong Creditionals');
                    }
                }
            }
            ajax.send("admin_username="+admin_username+"&admin_password="+admin_password);
        }
        function userSignUp() {
            var username = document.getElementById("sign_name").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("sign_password").value;
            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajax.open("POST", "login_test.php", true);
            ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
                    alert(ajax.responseText);
                }
            }
            ajax.send("signup_username="+username+"&signup_password="+password);
        }

        function showContent(conId){
            var current = document.getElementById(conId);
            if(current == document.getElementById("about-us")) {
                //hide if any links are opened
                document.getElementById("vision").style.position = "fixed";
                document.getElementById("projects").style.position = "fixed";
                document.getElementById("contactForm").style.position = "fixed";
                document.getElementById("login").style.position = "fixed";
                document.getElementById("home").style.position = "fixed";
                document.getElementById("home").style.left = "100%";
                document.getElementById("login").style.left = "100%";
                document.getElementById("contactForm").style.left = "100%";
                document.getElementById("vision").style.left = "100%";
                document.getElementById("projects").style.left = "100%";
                document.getElementById("projects").style.transition = "0.5s";
                document.getElementById("vision").style.transition = "0.5s";
                document.getElementById("contactForm").style.transition = "0.5s";
                document.getElementById("login").style.transition = "0.5s";
                document.getElementById("home").style.transition = "0.5s";

                //show the current link which user clicks
                current.style.position = "absolute";
                current.style.left = "0";
                current.style.transition = "left 1s";
//                current.style.right = "50px";


            }else if(current == document.getElementById("vision")){
                //change absolute to fixed position
                document.getElementById("about-us").style.position = "fixed";
                document.getElementById("projects").style.position = "fixed";
                document.getElementById("contactForm").style.position = "fixed";
                document.getElementById("login").style.position = "fixed";
                document.getElementById("home").style.position = "fixed";
                document.getElementById("home").style.left = "100%";
                //make left align 100%
                document.getElementById("contactForm").style.left = "100%";
                document.getElementById("login").style.left = "100%";
                document.getElementById("about-us").style.left = "100%";
                document.getElementById("projects").style.left = "100%";
                //transition 0.5s
                document.getElementById("about-us").style.transition = "0.5s";
                document.getElementById("projects").style.transition = "0.5s";
                document.getElementById("contactForm").style.transition = "0.5s";
                document.getElementById("login").style.transition = "0.5s";
                document.getElementById("home").style.transition = "0.5s";

                current.style.position = "absolute";
                current.style.left = "0";
                current.style.transition = "left 1s";
//                current.style.left = "50px";
            }else if(current == document.getElementById("projects")){
                document.getElementById("about-us").style.position = "fixed";
                document.getElementById("about-us").style.position = "fixed";
                document.getElementById("contactForm").style.position = "fixed";
                document.getElementById("login").style.position = "fixed";
                document.getElementById("home").style.position = "fixed";
                document.getElementById("home").style.left = "100%";
                document.getElementById("login").style.left = "100%";
                document.getElementById("contactForm").style.left = "100%";
                document.getElementById("about-us").style.left = "100%";
                document.getElementById("vision").style.position = "fixed";
                document.getElementById("vision").style.left = "100%";
                document.getElementById("vision").style.transition = "0.5s";
                document.getElementById("about-us").style.transition = "0.5s";
                document.getElementById("contactForm").style.transition = "0.5s";
                document.getElementById("login").style.transition = "0.5s";
                document.getElementById("home").style.transition = "0.5s";

                //show contents
                current.style.position = "absolute";
                current.style.left = "50";
                current.style.transition = "left 1s";
            }else if(current == document.getElementById("contactForm")){
                document.getElementById("vision").style.position = "fixed";
                document.getElementById("projects").style.position = "fixed";
                document.getElementById("about-us").style.position = "fixed";
                document.getElementById("login").style.position = "fixed";
                document.getElementById("home").style.position = "fixed";
                document.getElementById("home").style.left = "100%";
                document.getElementById("login").style.left = "100%";
                document.getElementById("about-us").style.left = "100%";
                document.getElementById("vision").style.left = "100%";
                document.getElementById("projects").style.left = "100%";
                document.getElementById("projects").style.transition = "0.5s";
                document.getElementById("about-us").style.transition = "0.5s";
                document.getElementById("vision").style.transition = "0.5s";
                document.getElementById("login").style.transition = "0.5s";
                document.getElementById("home").style.transition = "0.5s";

                current.style.position = "absolute";
                current.style.left = "0";
                current.style.transition = "left 1s";
            }else if(current == document.getElementById("login")){
                document.getElementById("vision").style.position = "fixed";
                document.getElementById("projects").style.position = "fixed";
                document.getElementById("about-us").style.position = "fixed";
                document.getElementById("contactForm").style.position = "fixed";
                document.getElementById("home").style.position = "fixed";
                document.getElementById("home").style.left = "100%";
                document.getElementById("about-us").style.left = "100%";
                document.getElementById("vision").style.left = "100%";
                document.getElementById("projects").style.left = "100%";
                document.getElementById("contactForm").style.left = "100%";
                document.getElementById("projects").style.transition = "0.5s";
                document.getElementById("about-us").style.transition = "0.5s";
                document.getElementById("vision").style.transition = "0.5s";
                document.getElementById("contactForm").style.transition = "0.5s";
                document.getElementById("home").style.transition = "0.5s";

                current.style.position = "absolute";
                current.style.left = "0";
                current.style.transition = "left 1s";
            }else if(current == document.getElementById("home")){
                document.getElementById("vision").style.position = "fixed";
                document.getElementById("projects").style.position = "fixed";
                document.getElementById("about-us").style.position = "fixed";
                document.getElementById("contactForm").style.position = "fixed";
                document.getElementById("login").style.position = "fixed";
                document.getElementById("login").style.left = "100%";
                document.getElementById("about-us").style.left = "100%";
                document.getElementById("vision").style.left = "100%";
                document.getElementById("projects").style.left = "100%";
                document.getElementById("contactForm").style.left = "100%";
                document.getElementById("projects").style.transition = "0.5s";
                document.getElementById("about-us").style.transition = "0.5s";
                document.getElementById("vision").style.transition = "0.5s";
                document.getElementById("contactForm").style.transition = "0.5s";
                document.getElementById("login").style.transition = "0.5s";


                current.style.position = "absolute";
                current.style.left = "0";
                current.style.transition = "left 1s";
            }
        }
        function show(item) {
            if(item == 'admin_login'){
                alert('admin');
            }
            if(item == 'sign_up'){
                alert('sign_up');
            }
            if(item == 'log_in'){
                alert('member');
            }
        }
    </script>
```

**CSS Code**

```
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: myFont;
        src: url("http://localhost/siyaramdevelopers/fonts/lucida-sans-unicode.woff");
    }
    body {
        font-family: myFont;
        background-color: black;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    #background {
        position: fixed;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        background: url("http://localhost/siyaramdevelopers/img/background.jpg");
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        z-index: 10;
    }
    #overlay {
        position: fixed;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        width: 100vw;
        background-color: black;
        height: 100vh;
        z-index: 20;
        opacity: 0.6;
        filter:alpha(opacity=60);
    }
    #mainContainer {
        position: absolute;
        /*border:1px solid yellow;*/
        z-index: 30;
        width: 80%;
        margin-left: 10%;
        margin-right: 10%;
    }
    #navlinks {
        position: fixed;
        height: 120px;
        width:100vw;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 40;
        background-color: rgba(12, 12, 12, 0.77);
    }
    #mainContainer > #navlinks > #menuContainer {
        width:600px;
        /*min-width: 600px;*/
        margin-top: 80px;
        position: absolute;
        right:10px;
        /*border:1px solid red;*/
        /*left: 50px;*/
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 635px) {
        body {
            overflow-x: auto;
        }
        #navlinks {
            position: absolute;
            width: 700px;
        }
        #mainContainer > #navlinks > #menuContainer {
            left:10px;
        }
        #mainContainer > #navlinks > #menuContainer > a {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

    }
    #mainContainer > #navlinks > #menuContainer > a {
        text-decoration: none;
        border: 2px solid white;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;;
        /*float: right;*/
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
        color: #fff;
        margin-top: 70px;
        outline: none;
    }
    #mainContainer > #navlinks > #menuContainer > a:hover {
        /*border: 2px solid white;*/
        background-color: rgba(28, 77, 233, 0.77);
        -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
        -moz-transition: 0.5s ;
        -ms-transition: 0.5s ;
        -o-transition: 0.5s ;
        transition: 0.5s ;
    }
    #logo {
        position: fixed;
        margin-left: 50px;
        width: 150px;
        /*border:2px solid blue;*/
    }
    #middle {
        margin-top: 150px;
        color: #fff;
    }
    #about-us, #vision, #projects, #contactForm, #login {
        position: fixed;
        width: 90%;
        /*top: 150px;*/
        /*right:100px;*/
        left:100%;
    }
    #middle > #about-us > p > img {
        margin-right: 20px;
    }
    #vision > img, #about-us > img, #contactForm > img, #projects > img {
        display: none;
    }
    /*Contact-us page style*/
    h3 {
        text-align: center;
    }
    #admin_login, #sign_up, #log_in {
        width:100%;
        height:40px;
        background: transparent;
        border: 2px solid white;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        color: #fff;
        outline:none;
        font-size: medium;
    }
    form[name=contact-form], form[name=loginForm], form[name=signupForm], form[name=admin_login]{
        /*border: 1px solid red;*/
        text-align: center;
    }
    form[name=contact-form] > input[type=text],
    form[name=contact-form] > input[type=number],
    form[name=contact-form] > input[type=email],
    form[name=loginForm] > input[type=email],
    form[name=loginForm] > input[type=password],
    form[name=loginForm] > input[type=button],
    form[name=signupForm] > input[type=text],
    form[name=signupForm] > input[type=email],
    form[name=signupForm] > input[type=password],
    form[name=signupForm] > input[type=number],
    form[name=signupForm] > input[type=button],
    form[name=admin_login] > input[type=email],
    form[name=admin_login] > input[type=password],
    form[name=admin_login] > input[type=button]
    {
        height: 40px;
        width:250px;
        margin: 10px;
        background: transparent;
        border: 2px solid white;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        color: #fff;
        outline:none;
        font-size: medium;
    }
    form[name=contact-form] > textarea {
        width:250px;
        background: transparent;
        border:2px solid white;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: medium;
        outline:none;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        resize: none;
    }
    form[name=contact-form] > input[type=submit] {
        width:250px;
        height: 40px;
        border:2px solid white;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-size: medium;
        background: transparent;
        color: #fff;
        outline:none;
    }
    form[name=loginForm] > a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
    }
    #admin_login, #sign_up, #logForm {
        border: 2px solid white;
        background-color: transparent;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-size: medium;
        margin-top: 0;
        padding: 5px;
        color: #fff;
        outline: none;
    }
    form[name=admin_login], form[name=loginForm], form[name=signupForm] {
        display: inline;
    }
    form[name=admin_login] > #username, form[name=loginForm] > #username, form[name=signupForm] > #name {
        margin-top: 30px;

    }
</style>
```

and this is screen-shot of Chrome 
[image]

this is in Safari
[image]

Comment: so, it's just the images/styling that's not working? if you get rid of all the javascript (which seems irrelevant) and make a minimal complete and verifiable example of html+css that demonstrates this issue - alternitvely check the console and network tabs in the developer tools (safari has developer tools I assume) to see if there's anything glaringly obvious happening there (404 errors and such)

Comment: I have checked but there is no errors like this :(

Comment: I have also removed background image to check but it's not working yet.

Comment: And now I have removed java script too.. but not working

Comment: You are using safari for windows ? Latest version is from [May 9, **2012**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history). Don't use it ! It's out of date, probably missing a lot of security fixes, and not at all representative of what mac os users of Safari will actually experience. Don't loose your time trying to fix bugs you'll encounter on this browser, even Apple doesn't spend any time on it.

Comment: Thanks, @Kaiido... I did not see the last update of safari :P. hihihi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it :). It takes some time but now I know why my code is not running correctly on Safari.

I have to test my css code one by one by commenting it. Offf.! 
But when I comment

```
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
```

I got some result. Then I changed it to

```
width:100%;
height:100%;
```

And it works! 
Now, I don't know that vh or vw is supported or not in Safari because when I used % in place of vh and vw my code run Correctly.

Comment: I honestly suspected vw/vh - but it's good you figured it out for yourself (which version of safari by the way)

Comment: I was using safari for windows, which is out dated now!. I just wasted my too much time to fix that... LOL